# Understanding Pytorch Tensor Slicing

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, tensor

Let `a` and `b` be two PyTorch tensors with `a.shape=[A,3]` and `b.shape=[B,3]`. Further `b` is of type `long`.

Then I know there are several ways slicing `a`. For example,

```
c = a[N1:N2:jump,[0,2]] # N1<N2<A
```

would return `c.shape = [2,2]` for N1=1 and N2=4 and jump=2.

But the below should have thrown a error,

```
c = a[b]
```

but instead `c.shape = [B,3,3]`.

For example,

```
a = torch.rand(10,3)
b = torch.rand(20,3).long()
print(a[b].shape) #torch.Size([20, 3, 3])
```

Can someone explain how the slicing is working for `a[b]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Basics

- When you use a[b], PyTorch is performing advanced indexing.
- In this case, each row of the tensor b is treated as an index into the first dimension of a, and the corresponding rows of a are returned.
- Since b has shape [B,3], this means that each row of b is a 3-element index into the first dimension of a. So the result of a[b] will have shape [B,3,d], where d is the number of columns in a.

## For example

suppose that b has the following values:

```
b = torch.tensor([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [1,2,3]])
```

- Then the result of a[b] will be a tensor with shape [3,3,3], where the first dimension corresponds to the three rows of b and the second dimension corresponds to the three indices in each row of b. The third dimension corresponds to the three columns of a.

Here's how the values are computed:

- The first row of b is [0,1,2].
- This means that the first row of a is returned,
- followed by the second row of a, and then the third row of a.
- So the first "slice" of the result will be:

```
[[a[0,0], a[0,1], a[0,2]],
 [a[1,0], a[1,1], a[1,2]],
 [a[2,0], a[2,1], a[2,2]]]
```

The second row of b is [3,4,5].

- This means that the fourth row of a is returned,
- followed by the fifth row of a,
- and then the sixth row of a.
- So the second "slice" of the result will be:

```
[[a[3,0], a[3,1], a[3,2]],
 [a[4,0], a[4,1], a[4,2]],
 [a[5,0], a[5,1], a[5,2]]]
```

The third row of b is [1,2,3].

- This means that the second row of a is returned,
- followed by the third row of a,
- and then the fourth row of a.
- So the third "slice" of the result will be:

```
[[a[1,0], a[1,1], a[1,2]],
 [a[2,0], a[2,1], a[2,2]],
 [a[3,0], a[3,1], a[3,2]]]
```

All of these slices are concatenated along the first dimension to produce the final result with shape [3,3,3].